# Jetpack Compose Circular Progress Indicator background color missing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack-compose

I am trying to implement the circular progress indicator using jetpack compose (docs for reference
[Cirular Progress Indicator Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#CircularProgressIndicator(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.StrokeCap)))
in the docs they have mentioned the `backgroundColor` property, but inside the source code of `CircularProgressIndicator` this property is missing

[image: Circular Progress Indicator Source Code Image]

[image: Circular Progress Indicator Source Code Image]

I have the latest compose bom dependency and using material 2

```
    // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#setup-compose
    def composeBom = platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')
    implementation composeBom
    androidTestImplementation composeBom

    // COMPOSE UI
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'

    // MATERIAL 2
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material'
```

Is this property missing?.
how can i add a background color to the circular progress indicator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update the `compose-material` dependency
[compose-materail Version 1.4.0-alpha04 change log](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.4.0-alpha04)(refer point 3)

If you update your library to compose-material 1.4.0-alpha04, the background property is now available for circular progress indicators under the param name of
`backgroundColor` (for Material 2)
or `trackColor` (for Material 3)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CircularProgressIndicator(
        modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Blue)
        .padding(16.dp) // increase it as much you want to expand it's background area
)
```

Comment: backgroundColor property of CircularProgressIndicator is for The color of the background behind the indicator, Your code adds background to entire composable.

Comment: Refer Docs link for reference